# ag-grid modify date filter display

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I use ag-grid on my Angular 4 app to display a table. In the date column, I use default date filter `agDateColumnFilter` as in the documentation. The placeholder shown in the filter input is always `mm/dd/yyyy`. Is it possible to change it to `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Answer (score 3):

I currently have the same problem.

Since ag-grid uses `input type="date"` for its date filter it suffers from the restrictions mentioned here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/885338
. I can only wonder what lead to the horrible decision not to let the display format be editable.

You can verify it by changing the browser's language.

The only solution I currently see is to implement a custom filter as described here -> http://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-date-component/

If you want somekind of popup calendar be aware that you might have to fiddle with ag-grid's CSS, most notably some `overflow` properties (on class `ag-root` for example) and I don't know what the effects this has on ag-grid.

Answer (score 2):

we can do this with the moment

```
{headerName: "Updated at", field: "updated_at", hide: true, cellFormatter: function(data) {
    return moment(data.value).format('L');
}}
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1029) for further information

Comment: thank you for the reference, I was able to format the whole data row as I wanted, but the filter input still remains the issue. I still have to type `mm/dd/yyyy` to filter data rows while they are in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. And the placeholder in filter input is still `mm/dd/yyyy` as default

Comment: @Sachila :can you tell me sir how to get selected value from date filter?

Answer (score 1):

Use **browserDatePicker: true** in **filterParams** property